# JS Apply Array Prototype "indexOf" and "splice" On Object Instead of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

We have a simple object with methods

```
var o = {
   fn : (a)=>{}
}
```

We than add numerical indexed sub objects to it

```
o[0] = {};
o[1] = {};
```

So now we have a mixture of methods and numeric properties

```
o = {
   "0" : {}...
   "1" : {}...
   fn  : (a)=>{}
}
```

This is helpful for various reasons... seems totally legit and possible in JS.

We preferred an object with numeric properties, instead of an array with methods.

**The Question : is there a way to get indexOf, splice, various `Array.prototype` methods to work with this?**

We have tried stuff like :

```
[].indexOf.call(o,_index) // didn't work
```

...

Is the only solution would be to construct our object as an array, appending methods to it? or maybe there is another way to apply `Array.prototype` methods on an object?

Comment: This is object not array, and why you need indexOf  when you can directly access `o[index]` and for any array method use `object.keys(), Object.values or Object.entries` and then access key and values

Comment: Maybe you would be happier starting with an array and adding a `fn` property to it.

Comment: *"is there a way to get indexOf, splice, various Array.prototype methods to work with this"* And how would this work with an object exactly?

Comment: because we need to know the exact index of some nested object, for splice removing it, or various jobs. we can create a utility function to iterate the numerical props, but we wanted to ask if someone knows how to do it without creating more functions...

Comment: You can [access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Browser_compatibility) object by it's key and you have [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) method to remove particular key/value

Comment: @CodeManiac this is what we finally went with... the elegant Object.Assign solution is a problem with IE.

Comment: You can do all these operations on object as well. For ex: `indexOf` would be `Object.keys(o).find(k=> o[k] === value)`. And `splice` would be to loop from `start` to `end` index and `delete o[index]`

Comment: @adiga this seems like a good enough solution which works with IE as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give you object a `length` property you can hack your way into the array methods through the back door. I suspect nobody would really *advise* doing this, but the way the JS spec is written to look for `length` and iterate over sequential numbers, many of these methods will work:

```js
let o = {
  "0" : "zero",
  "1" : "one",
  length: 3,
  fn  : (a)=>{},
  "2" : "Two",
}

console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(o, 1))

console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(o, "Two"))

Array.prototype.splice.call(o, 1, 0, "Three")
// spliced in and adjusted length
console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an array as target. The result is an array with all array methods.

```js
var o = { 0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', fn: a => {} };

console.log(Object.assign([], o).indexOf('bar'));
```

For IE, you could reduce the keys.

```js
var o = { 0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', fn: a => {}, '1.1': 'wrong', '-1': 'wrong', 1e10: 'wrong' },
    array = Object.keys(o).reduce((r, i) => {
        if (isNaN(i) || +i < 0 || +i !== +i | 0) return r;
        r[i] = o[i];
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(array.indexOf('bar'));
console.log(array);
```